# Java regexp - Double negative lookahead - ignore parenthesis - ignore lines starting with '-'

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to cover off two scenarios within a string function.

1. Ignore ';' if in parenthesis
2. Ignore ';' if line starts with '--'

I have a large string containing multiple SQL statements, which I need to split on ';' except in the above scenarios where there is a commented block, or the semi-colon exists in a function - ironically such as REGEXP()

I have tried to put a second negative lookahead block before or after the existing, but it never seems to work.

`String[] queries = queryParam.trim().split(";(?![^()]*\\))");` -- Works for parenthesis

`String[] queries = queryParam.trim().split(";(?![^()]*\\))(?!-*\-)");` -- Does not work

`String[] queries = queryParam.trim().split(";(?!-*\-)(?![^()]*\\))");` -- Does not work

https://regex101.com/r/Sdx8TC/1

Comment: You should not parse SQL with regex

Comment: Think 'parsing' is a bit strong for whats happening here.  Its splitting a SQL script file.   But thanks for the contribution

Comment: Have some example lines and/or a regex101?

Comment: Edited with regex101 link

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this regex:

```
((?:(?:\-\-[^*]*+(?:[^\-\-][^*]*\-\-)*|(?:[^\-\-]|\-\-\n?)*?\n)|(?:\((?:\(.|[^\(])*\(|\((?:\).|[^\)])*\)|.[^\)\;]*))*?)(;)
```

The regex ensures the following:

1. Ignore ';' if in parenthesis
2. Ignore ';' if line starts with '--'

Link to see the regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/AFnWqD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your second requirement is `if line starts with '--'`. In that case the negative lookahead `(?!-*\-)` is not going to work because your match starts with `;` so that line can not start with `--` anymore.

What you might do using your patterns is first check if the string starts with -- using for example matches in combination with this pattern:

```
^[ \\t]*--.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9S3KIb/1)

If that matches, then use split with your pattern:

```
;(?![^()]*\\))
```

For example:

```
String[] strings = {
    "   --hello;(hello;hello)hello;",
    "hello;(hello;hello)hello;"
};

for (String s : strings) {
    if (!s.matches("^[ \\t]*--.*$")) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(";(?![^()]*\\))")));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[hello, (hello;hello)hello]
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/bctenA)

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for taking the time. Unfortunately it works on the basis that the queries are already split into elements of an array, where its actually just one large string, so I am not able to evaluate whether the line starts with '--' or not before splitting.

Comment: @ChrisFinlayson Thank you, but if it is one string, how do you want to differentiate between different statements: Using the `;`?

Comment: Tokenise the string, splitting on ';' - EXCEPT for cases of scenario 1 and 2 (comment lines or where the character exists in brackets)